# How to do NOT filter for multiValued fieldType in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, filter

I don't know the term of this filter, so I will just show an example of my Solr document and the result I want it to be.

## my Solr Document

```
[
  {
    product : "Awesome T-Shirt 1",
    size : [ "L", "S" ]
  },
  {
    product : "Awesome T-Shirt 2",
    size : [ "L" ]
  },
  {
    product : "Awesome T-Shirt 3",
    size : [ "S", "M" ]
  }
]
```

## I use `-size:L` in query filter and the result is

```
[
  {
    product : "Awesome T-Shirt 3",
    size : [ "S", "M" ]
  }
]
```

## but I want this result

```
[
  {
    product : "Awesome T-Shirt 1",
    size : [ "L", "S" ]
  },
  {
    product : "Awesome T-Shirt 3",
    size : [ "S", "M" ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

> -size:L  AND size(S M)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not the answer I want, I can't do `size(S M)` cause there will be others scenarios like `["S", "X"]` `["S", "XL"]`